# Visual C#: How to find out *which* assembly or reference I am missing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012.  I understand that when I use new types, I need their using directive.  I understand that different using directives require different assemblies or references.

I am fairly new to MS VS.  Is there a simple way to find out *which* assembly or reference needs added for a particular using directive?

Example:

I just used the type `FileContentResult`.
This is in `System.Web.Mvc`.
Which assembly or reference do I add?

Again, I am asking for the **general** case, not just this case in particular.  Ideally, I would like a trick I can use every time this happens, to quickly find the reference I need to add.

Comment: Invest in Resharper Plugin. It does the work for you. And much more. Doesn't matter if you are a home user or pro. This tool is one of the most important ones for C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which missing DLL is making my .NET application crash on startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491240/how-do-i-find-out-which-missing-dll-is-making-my-net-application-crash-on-start)

Comment: @Liam I think this is different as he is in design time, not runtime.

Comment: Although I back the use of resharper, I still think you should know how to find the assembly without it. Being too dependent upon the tooling is damaging.

Comment: By the way: a `using` directive is *not* the same as an assembly reference! You *need* to use an assembly ref to add "other" assembies and you *may* use "usings" so you don't need to write the namespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not to sound to terribly old and crass, but the right way to figure out which assembly your types are in is to *read the documentation*.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Web.Mvc
>
> Assembly:  System.Web.Mvc (in System.Web.Mvc.dll)

If you're looking for something more immediate, the typical naming convention for .NET types is that they will be in an assembly that matches their namespace, or one of its parents, so start with the namespace you're trying to add and work backwards until you find a file with that name.

Unfortunately, there's no *rule* that things work this way, so you'll always have exceptions. One that drives me absolutely crazy is `EntityFramework.dll` does not contain the `EntityFramework` namespace, but rather `System.Data.Entity`, I assume because Microsoft was thinking -- I dunno what they were thinking, it's stupid. But at least MSDN helps you out there; for third party assemblies with bad names and no documentation, your best bet is to track down an assembly that looks like it might be related to what you're trying to use and `ildasm` and/or add it as a reference, and scan the metadata.

Comment: I mean, generally they're named the same as well though.

Comment: @Michael: No worries, no offense taken. This is the type of answer I was looking for. Fwiw, I was already in the MSDN docs, just at the wrong spot. I have never had much luck with them. Perhaps my *real* task is to learn how to use the docs effectively!

Comment: I just googled the full type name, MSDN is almost always the first link that comes up.